# FAXCOMEX Silent Printing HTML file

Tags: internet-explorer, vba

I have a successful implementation of a FAXCOMEX VisualBasic app, and I'm currently facing a problem that whenever HTML files are added to be faxed, it displays a print dialog and waits for the user to click "Print".  Clicking print then allows the fax to be sent as normal.  This dialog must be opening from Internet Explorer, as all other files open in their default programs.

Is there a way to get rid of this prompt so that it sends automatically or clicks print automatically?

I've tried changing the default program for HTML files to Chrome and Firefox, but that does not work at all and throws exceptions.  I read that I can change the default program to Word, but that causes some formatting issues especially with images and tables and does not allow input boxes and other HTML items to print.

Comment: Basically, the question is, is there a setting or a way of making Internet Explorer print without having to show the print dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolved it myself.  I created a VBScript that I executed just before assigning the .bodies property.  This script activates the "Print" app and then presses enter twice to click the print button.